# Почему значение в списке не пропадает?

Tags: python

```
a = list(str(input("Text: ")))
b = list(str(input("Text2: ")))

counter = 0
for i in a:
    if a[counter] == b[counter]:
        new_gen = list(a[counter])
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        continue
    print(new_gen)
```

Я думал что список в который записываются новые значения в цикле перезаписываются, тем самым накопить элементы невозможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы присваиваете переменной 1 символ

```
new_gen = list(a[counter])
```

, поэтому накопления никакого и нет

чтобы накапливать можно было бы делать так:

```
new_gen += list(a[counter])
```

или

```
new_gen += [a[counter]]
```

или

```
new_gen.append(a[counter])
```

Кстати в вашем коде очень много лишнего -

1. ненужный счетчик `counter`, когда можно пройтись по позиции
2. ненужный `continue`, там и так переход в начало списка будет
3. дублирование `counter += 1`, хотя можно было вынести за условие

Но самое главное - **у вас ошибка!!!**

Если первая строка будет больше второй, то возникнет ситуация, когда ко второй строке будет обращение по индексы за пределами этой строки и будет ошибка

Например код можно было бы переписать так:

**вариант 1:**

```
new_gen = []
for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        new_gen.append(a[i])
print(new_gen)
```

Если же говорить про короткие коды, то можно сделать такие варианты:

**вариант 2:**

```
new_gen = []
for obj in zip(a, b):
    if obj[0] == obj[1]:
        new_gen.append(obj[0])
```

и конечно все можно будет свернуть в 1 строку

**вариант 3:**

```
new_gen = [obj[0] for obj in zip(a, b) if obj[0] == obj[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, в данном случае вы перезаписываете переменную.

```
a = list(input("Text: "))
b = list(input("Text2: "))

counter = 0
for i in a:
    if a[counter] == b[counter]:
        new_gen = list(a[counter])
    counter += 1
    print(new_gen)
```

Если вы хотите чтоб переменная накапливала символы то сделайте так

```
a = list(input("Text: "))
b = list(input("Text2: "))
new_gen = []
counter = 0
for i in a:
    if a[counter] == b[counter]:
        new_gen.append(a[counter])
    counter += 1
print(new_gen)
```